# Get ListView items that are checked

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, tags

I have listview with combox=true containg images. Each item is assigned a tag.
I can get tag of focussed item:

```
string name = this.lstview1.FocusedItem.Tag.ToString();
```

I can get index of checked item:

```
  list = lstview1.CheckedIndices.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

How do I get the tag of the checked item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CheckedItems` property instead of `CheckedIndices`:

```
var selectedTags = this.listView1.CheckedItems
                                 .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(x => x.Tag);
```

Anyway, also `CheckedIndices` can be used, e.g.:

```
var selectedTags = this.listView1.CheckedIndices
                                 .Cast<int>()
                                 .Select(i => this.listView1.Items[i].Tag);
```

**EDIT:**

Little explanation of LINQ [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx):

The following code:

```
var selectedTags = this.listView1.CheckedItems
                                 .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(x => x.Tag);
foreach(var tag in selectedTags)
{
   // do some operation using tag
}
```

is functionally equal to:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in this.listView1.CheckedItems)
{
   var tag = item.Tag;
   // do some operation using tag
}
```

In this particular example is not so useful, nor shorter in term of code length, but, believe me, in many situations LINQ is really really helpful.

Comment: What indicates (i)  i=>, and (x )   x=>x.tag

Comment: Is a lambda expression used in a `IEnumerable<T>.Select()`. It's a projection of the `IEnumerable` on which is called the `Select()` to another `IEnumerable`. The first basically says: take each element of `CheckedItems` (calling it x) and for each yield `x.Tag`. So you will get an `IEnumerable<object>` containing all Tags corresponding to `CheckedItems`. (Hope to be clear, english is not my first language...)

Comment: Added a little explanation at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var x = listView1.Items[listView1.CheckedIndices.Cast().ToList().First()].Tag;
```

?

Comment: Thanx for code.But How can I make  index of it for for loop. AS first always indicate first element of sequence.